# C# Generics cant pass a list

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types

Im pretty new to generics and am trying to build myself a helper method for creating 2 dimensional object array as below.

```
public static class CarouselHelper<T> where T : new()
{
    public static IEnumerable<T[,]> BuildCarousel(T data, int rows, int columns)
    {
        T [,] carousel = new T[rows, columns];
        List<T[,]> slides = new List<T[,]>();

        int rowCount = 0, columnCount = 0, itemCount = 1;


        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            if (itemCount % 2 == 0)
            {
                rowCount = 0;
                columnCount = columnCount++;
            }

            carousel[rowCount, columnCount] = item;


            if (rowCount == rows && columnCount == columns)
            {
                slides.Add(carousel);
                carousel = new T[rows, columns];
            }

            itemCount = itemCount++;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Im calling the method as follows

```
var bob = Common.CarouselHelper<List<VideoListModel>>.BuildCarousel(ds, 2, 4);
```

I get the following error when I run and not sure where to go from here?

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'T' because 'T' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: You never return carousel ... this method will always return null. Further after your fix that, your result will be a List of the same exact object all equal to the last carousel, because it's a reference type and you're reusing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is quite still. You're trying to iterate over `T` instance, without being sure it's possible.

It's hard to tell how to fix this without knowledge what is `ds` type, but you should probably change your method declaration to be:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[,]> BuildCarousel(IEnumerable<T> data, int rows, int columns)
```

btw. You never increment `rowCount`, so it's always set to `0`. Are you sure the algorithm is correct?

Comment: Good point well put on the rowCount lol, as Ive been wrapped up in trying to learn generics I never noticed that - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cant *use* any methods on your generic type that might not exist, its all still statically typed,

ie you have

```
foreach (var item in data)
```

and data is type T,  and so T must be IEnumerable, and so you need to explicitly constrain the generic type, ie

```
public static class CarouselHelper<T> where T : new(), IEnumerable
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Setting that kind of constrains may cause boxing/unboxing issues when `T is IEnumerable<TItem>` and `TItem` is value type.

Comment: There are many possibilities hence the link,  I personally care little for boxing worries in general.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help on that, Ill take a look at the link :)

Comment: Ive update the class def to public static class CarouselHelper<T> where T : IEnumerable<T>, new() but I now get an error on the call as its expecting an Enumerable list so when I pass a list in it tries to convert to IEnumerable<mylist>

Comment: you really want T to be an enumerable of itself?

my 'guess' from your comments is you just want the method to convert a list of anything into a square array and so you probably actually want:
CarouselHelper<T> where T : new()
public static T[,] BuildCarousel(IEnumerable<T> data, int rows, int columns)
var bob = Common.CarouselHelper<VideoListModel>.BuildCarousel(ds, 2, 4)
but there's some guess work involved there, type of ds may help.

Comment: Close I think, I just cant get my head round it as I have already tried that but get the following error Error 12 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SWA.UI.Models.VideoListModel>' to 'SWA.UI.Models.VideoListModel' you are correct with the general interpretation of what im trying to do, just reordering a list as a 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that `T` is your fundamental data type. It's not enumerable: the `IEnumerable<T>` needs to be in the method prototype's declaration of its `data` argument.

But it seems awfully...complicated. Why don't you do something simpler, like this?

```
public static class CarouselHelper<T>
{
  public static IEnumerable<T[,]> BuildCarousel( IEnumerable<T> data, int rows, int cols )
  {
    List<T[,]> slides = new List<T[,]>();
    using ( IEnumerator<T> enumerator = data.GetEnumerator() )
    {
      bool moved = true ;
      do
      {
        T [,] carousel = new T[ rows, cols ] ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i )
        {
          for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; ++j )
          {
            moved = enumerator.MoveNext() ;
            T currentCell = moved ? enumerator.Current : default(T) ;
            carousel[i,j] = currentCell ;
          }
        }
        slides.Add(carousel) ;
      } while ( moved ) ;
    }
    return slides ;
  }
}
```

The above builds the 2d arrays out in row-major order; if you want them built in column-major order, just swap the nested `for` loops at the core:

```
T [,] carousel = new T[ rows, cols ] ;
for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; ++j )
{
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i )
  {
    moved = enumerator.MoveNext() ;
    T currentCell = moved ? enumerator.Current : default(T) ;
    carousel[i,j] = currentCell ;
  }
}
slides.Add(carousel) ;
```

Even better, since you're returning `IEnumerable<T>`... make the evaluation lazy:

```
public static class CarouselHelper<T>
{
  public static IEnumerable<T[,]> BuildCarousel( IEnumerable<T> data, int rows, int cols )
  {
    using ( IEnumerator<T> enumerator = data.GetEnumerator() )
    {
      bool moved = true ;
      do
      {
        T [,] carousel = new T[ rows, cols ] ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i )
        {
          for ( int j = 0 ; j < cols ; ++j )
          {
            moved = enumerator.MoveNext() ;
            T currentCell = moved ? enumerator.Current : default(T) ;
            carousel[i,j] = currentCell ;
          }
        }
        yield return carousel ;
      } while ( moved ) ;
    }
  }
}
```